# A calculation about Stoke's Formula in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, charge, conservation-laws

[image]

This is from the book by Carroll
the equations are $$Q=-\int _{\Sigma}d^3x\sqrt{\gamma} n_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{e
}  =-\int _{\Sigma}d^3x\sqrt{\gamma} n_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$$
$$Q=-\int _{\partial\Sigma}d^3x\sqrt{\gamma ^{(2)}}n_{\mu} \sigma _{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$
I have no idea how to get the equation below from above.
Intuitively I guess that it has sth to do with the Gaussian version of Stoke's theorem on this spacelike hypersurface, but that requires an induced derivative on this surface, and I don't know how to do it. If it's direct use of Stoke's formula, can you please show the details of calculating?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Having edited and Sorry for that.  I thought it is just a problem about special calculation so didn't bother to type by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $n_\mu F^{\mu \nu}$ is tangent to the hypersurface, by an argument of anti-symmetry. So :
\begin{align}
n_\mu P_\Sigma(\nabla_\nu F^{\mu \nu})\equiv& \gamma_\nu^\sigma \nabla_\sigma(n_\mu F^{\mu \nu})-\gamma^\sigma_\nu \nabla_\sigma n_\mu F^{\mu \nu}
\\ 
=& P_\Sigma(\nabla_\nu(n_\mu F^{\mu \nu}))-P_\Sigma(\nabla_\nu n_\mu)F^{\mu \nu}
\\ 
\stackrel{!}{=}& \nabla_\nu(n_\mu F^{\mu \nu})-P_\Sigma(\nabla_\nu n_\mu)F^{\mu \nu}
\end{align}
Where $P_\Sigma$ is the projection onto $\Sigma$. Then, you should use integration by parts:
\begin{equation}
-\int_\Sigma d^3x \sqrt{\gamma}\, n_\mu \nabla_\nu F^{\mu \nu}=-\int_{\partial\Sigma} d^2x \sqrt{\gamma^{(2)}}\, n_\mu \sigma_\nu F^{\mu \nu}+\int_\Sigma d^3x \sqrt{\gamma}\, \underbrace{P_\Sigma(\nabla_\nu n_\mu)}_{\equiv K_{\mu \nu}}  F^{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
But since the extrinsic curvature $K_{\mu \nu}$ is symmetric, the second term vanishes, and only the first remains.

Comment: Could you please explain why you can use formula here since the derivative is not on the hypersurface and why $K_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric? Note that $n_{\nu}$ is normalized.

Comment: @AlbertLiu I've edited the answer. BTW, it is a well-known fact that the extrinsic curvature is symmetric.